# ipywidgets incomatible with Python 3.8

Tags: conda, ipywidgets, python-3.8

Is there a conda version of  "ipywidgets" which is compatible with Python 3.8 ?

I am getting the following error while trying to install using "conda install -c anaconda ipywidgets".

Error : UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Comment: Run `conda search ipywidgets` and see for yourself. It's only a matter of time until Anaconda releases Python 3.8 builds of the frequently used packages.

Comment: Thanks. I tried couple of available options and all fails. Hope the release some new soon